# PostgreSQL: How to get only the first result from a SELECT

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my database, I have two columns, products, and products_photos, where products can have many products_photos. What I want to do is a query that returns the products but with only one photo.
I manage to write a query like this:

```
SELECT products.*, file
FROM products, products_photos
WHERE products.id = products_photos.product_id
ORDER BY products.id
```

But still, this returns the same product, multiple times, because of the photos.
I already tried to use DISTINCT and LIMIT but does not work properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Second, Postgres has a very convenient extension, `DISTINCT ON`, that does what you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (p.id) p.*, pp.file
FROM products JOIN
     products_photos pp
     ON p.id = pp.product_id
ORDER BY p.id
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks for the help. I will study further on this subject.

Comment: +1 For the readable JOIN syntax. Unbelievable that the prehistoric no-join syntax is still used in the 21st century...

Comment: @FrankHeikens: to be fair, unfortunately the Postgres manual still mainly shows the implicit joins in the WHERE clause. This will change with Postgres 14 however where the manual prefers to use the explicit JOIN syntax.

Answer (score 0):

There's a more readable version of this that I like a lot more:

```
SELECT products.*, file
FROM products, products_photos
WHERE products.id = products_photos.product_id
ORDER BY products.id
fetch first 1 row only
```